# I want to create a matrix form a worksheet of data in columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a worksheet that looks like this:
[image: worksheet of data]

I want to (automatically) create a matrix that looks like this:

[image: worksheet of resulting matrix]

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly should be done automatically? Ultimate solution is a macro, but if you have already the lists and you need to put only `X`s, then you can solve it also with formulas.

Comment: The "data" spreadsheet is going to be variable, I will be adding data to it as I get it... but I would like to generate the matrix from the data automatically so I don't have to build it.  I do not know how to write a macro and would be very grateful for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do with formulas. 
For simplicity, I put the matrix
into Columns `C`-`N` (and beyond) of the primary worksheet;
moving it to another sheet (page/tab) is trivial.

This is a job for the `SEARCH` function,
which looks for one string within another, like “anti” within “frantic”. 
We will use it to look for each individual property
(“analgesic”, “antibacterial”, etc.) in the list of properties
(“antiseptic, antifungal, analgesic, antitumoral, etc.”). 
`SEARCH` returns the position of the substring —
for example, `SEARCH("anti", "frantic")` returns 3,
because “a” is the third character of “frantic”. 
We don’t care about that; we care about the fact that,
if the first string is present in the second one, `SEARCH` returns a number,
and otherwise it returns an error. 
So, if we put `ISERROR(SEARCH(C$1, $B2))` into cell `C2`,
it returns FALSE if “antiseptic” (`C1`) is in the list of properties
for Lavender (`B2`), and TRUE otherwise. 
So

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(C$1, $B2)), "", "x")
```

displays `x` if the property is on the list and blank if it isn’t.

But that’s an oversimplification. 
If a list of properties includes “antibacterial (powerful)”,
then a search for “antibacterial” will succeed. 
Your illustration of your desired matrix
suggests that you don’t want this to happen. 
There’s a standard trick for this: search for “, antibacterial,”
(with commas at the beginning and end),
to find “antibacterial” as a complete entry in the list. 
But that won’t match
if “antibacterial” is the first or the last entry in the list —
so we add commas at the beginning and the end of the list, too.

So, put `=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(", "&C$1&",", ", "&$B2&",")), "", "x")`
into cell `C2`, and drag down and to the right:

[image: matrix]

Comment: Still going to need to create the headings for each Medical Property, keep them consistent. Still, I like it as a pure Excel solution, rather than using some tool (CLI) to parse a CSV file creating another one, as I was originally tempted to suggest.